# Pass macro to \pyv

Tags: pythontex

I use Pythontex for formatting Python source code. I store code in a macro. I need to pass this code to one of the Pythontex commands (e.g. `\pyv`) and get the formatted code.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
    \def\foo{x = 3}
    \pyv{\foo}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

```
\foo
```

The macro `\pys` does this, but doesn't format the code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can use `\expandafter\pyv\expandafter{\foo}`. This causes the `\foo` macro to be expanded before `\pyv`.